# Javascript Split from parentheses and make condition statement with AND /OR

Tags: javascript, algorithm, conditional-statements, where-clause, parentheses

I want to make condition statement from the string includes parentheses, AND and OR.

So i found the codes that split string with parenthese from stackoverflow.

```js
let array = [],
  c = 0;

'(A OR B) AND C'.split(/([()])/).filter(Boolean).forEach(e =>
  e == '(' ? c++ : e == ')' ? c-- : c > 0 ? array.push('(' + e + ')') : array.push(e)
);

let finalQuery = [];
while (array.length > 0) {
  const condition = array.pop();
  // console.log(condition)
  if (condition.includes("OR")) {
    let temp = condition.trim().split(" OR ");
    temp.map(each => {
      finalQuery.push(each);
    })
  } else if (condition.includes("AND")) {
    let temp = condition.trim();
    if (temp.includes("AND")) {
      if (temp.indexOf("AND") == 0) {
        if (finalQuery.length > 0) {
          finalQuery = finalQuery.map(x => x + " " + temp.replace("AND", ""))
        }
      } else if (temp.indexOf("AND") == temp.length - 3) {
        if (finalQuery.length > 0) {
          finalQuery = finalQuery.map(x => temp.replace("AND", "") + ' ' + x)
        }
      }
    }

  }
  console.log(finalQuery)
}
```

I tried the codes above.

But it doesn't work.

I want results like below.

Input: `(A OR B) AND (C OR D)`

Output: `A C OR A D OR  B C OR B D`

Input: `(A OR B) AND (C OR D) AND (E OR F)`

Output: `A C E OR A C F OR A D E OR A D F OR B C E OR B C F OR B D E OR B D F`

Could anyone help me about it?

Comment: please add the wanted result from the given strings.

Comment: sorry, I added it above.

Comment: You would have to include some form of recursion in your code.  For example: Before you finish the `while()` loop check if `finalQuery` still contains bracketed items.  If it does, remove everything from that and push it back onto `array`.  The `while()` test will then see that `array` still has content and will keep looping.

Comment: You are basically writing an interpreter for a domain specific language. If you'd like to (and I would recommend it), you could write your own interpreter. Complete with a grammar/AST, a parser/tokenizer, and a runtime. A quick google search got me [this](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part1/), which seems to be a good guide. Or you could go straight to the classics and read ["Build Your Own Lisp"](http://www.buildyourownlisp.com/)

Comment: I have a question about format of input. As `condition = X AND/OR Y`, does the input has only like `(condition) AND/OR (condition) AND/OR ...` with parenthesis or not?

Comment: @JoonaYoon Yes, you are right, ```(condition) AND/OR (condition) AND/OR ...```

Comment: @SehunPark Then make the condition to set/group and **multiple** (or join) the groups when reached separator `AND` or **merge** when separator is `OR` for every interval between `(` and `)`. I think it can be resolved as like arithmetic 
 calculator problem (using stack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for format by `A AND/OR B AND/OR C ...`,

let's assume that

- *A* is *token* also *B* is *token* too
- *operation* is only one of `AND` and `OR`
- `expression = token opertaor token`.  - *(1)*

I evaluate all *expressions* to *token* as string. and I have some **rules** for it:

- `A OR B` -> `A,B` (tokens as string)
- `A AND B` -> `AB`
- then, `A,B AND C` can be evaluated to `AC,BC`

parse and get expression by bracket `(` and `)`, and evaluated it.

For example, `(A AND B) OR C` is evaluated to `AB OR C` and do it again to `AB,C`. Now we can evaluated all expression by above *(1)*

here code is. Try it:

```js
function is_exp(s){
    return s.indexOf(' OR ') !== -1 || s.indexOf(' AND ') !== -1;
}

// return "exp oper exp" to evaluated exp
function eval(s) {
    // OR operation
    if (s.indexOf('OR') != -1) {
        var i = s.indexOf('OR');
        var first = s.slice(0, i - 1);
        var second = s.slice(i + 3);
        return [first, second].toString(); // merge
    }
    // AND operation
    else if (s.indexOf('AND') != -1) {
        var i = s.indexOf('AND');
        var first = s.slice(0, i - 1).split(',');
        var second = s.slice(i + 4).split(',');
        var result = [];
        for(var f0 of first) {
            for(var s0 of second) {
                result.push(f0 + s0);
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    // wrong and fail
    else {
        return "";
    }
}

function _calculate(s) {
    var l = -1, r = Infinity;
    var tokens = [];
    var opers = [];
    while (l < s.length) {
        l = s.indexOf('(', l+1);
        if (r+1 < l) {
            opers.push(s.slice(r+1, l).replace(/\s/gi, ''));
        }
        r = s.indexOf(')', l);
        if (l == -1 || r == -1) break;
        var exp = s.slice(l+1, r);
        tokens.push(is_exp(exp) ? eval(exp) : exp); // if it is expression, evaluted it.
    }

    // evaluate all chained elements
    var result = tokens[0];
    for(var i=1; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
        result = eval(result + ' ' + opers[i-1] + ' ' + tokens[i]);
    }

    // make string as good to read
    var lst = result.split(',');
    lst = lst.map((v) => (v.split('').join(' '))); // "ABC" => "A B C"
    return lst.join(' or '); // add "OR" between all tokens
}

function calculate() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.value = _calculate(input.value);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', calculate);
```

```css
textarea { width: 100%; display: block; margin: 5px auto; }
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="2">(A OR B) AND (C OR D)</textarea>
<button onclick="calculate()">Run</button>
<textarea id="output" rows="2" disabled readonly></textarea>
```

BUT, In my code does NOT work with `(A AND (B OR C)) OR D`.

If you want to handle a case with above case, I suppose that can be solved with stack or recursion and parse more perfect on brackets.

Comment: @SehunPark Is this answer not useful for you to solve problem?

Comment: Sorry for late check. Your answer is really helpful. I got a hint from your codes and changed it little bit. It works well. Thank you :)